# Haskell: How to print multiple metrics of pure function results

Tags: haskell, io

I want to print out the average and length of a list of values resulting from a "pure" function call.  I've done a fair bit of research on this and just about to put my head through a wall.  The following code works:

```
[... a bunch of other stuff like "doParallelTrades" ...]

simulate :: Int -> Int -> [Double]
simulate numbuyers groupsize =
    let buyers = initTraders numbuyers minimum_price maximum_price
        sellers = initTraders numbuyers minimum_price maximum_price
    in doParallelTrades sellers buyers groupsize


{--
MAIN
--}

getNum :: IO Int
getNum = readLn

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let prices n = simulate n 0
  putStr "How many buyers?"
  n <- getNum
  start <- getCurrentTime
  print "average price = "
  print $ average $ prices n
  end <- getCurrentTime
  print "number of trades:"
  print $ length $ prices n
  print "Wall Time:"
  print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

However, this evaluates "prices n" twice, which obviously I don't want to do for large n.  I'd like to evaluate it just once, then compute and print the average, then print the length.  I tried changing the main function to:

```
main = do
  let prices n = simulate n 0
  putStr "How many buyers?"
  n <- getNum
  start <- getCurrentTime
  p <- prices n  -- ***********New Code*********
  print "average price = "
  print $ average $ p   -- ***********New Code**********
  end <- getCurrentTime
  print "number of trades:"
  print $ length $ p  -- **********New Code***********
  print "Wall Time:"
  print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

I.e., bind "prices n" to "p" and then do stuff with p.  But the interpreter gives me the error

```
zitraders-threaded.hs:162:8:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [Integer]’
                with actual type ‘[Double]’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: p <- prices n
```

I've researched various online resources but they are either too simple (working only within the IO monad) or too complex.  So how do I:

1. Get some input from the user.
2. Run some "pure" calculations on that input (just once) and store the result.
3. Tell the user multiple properties of that result.

Comment: Change `p <- prices n` to `let p = prices n`. The `<-` syntax is for monadic operations - in this case, the monad is IO, so anything appearing to the right of `<-` must have type `IO something`.

Comment: By the way, you probably want `putStrLn "average price = "` since `print` adds extra quotes.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 4):

You can not bind p with prices n with the '<-' operator, use a let instead:

This should do the trick:

```
main = do
  ...
  start <- getCurrentTime
  let p = prices n  -- ***********New Code*********
  print "average price = "
  ...
```